# I am new to RUBY and i need to understand 3 functions

Tags: c++, ruby, qt, ssl, openssl

I have been given the 3 functions below. Can anybody please help me to understand these? I am trying to port an application to C++ using Qt, but I don't understand these functions. So please help me!
Thanks in advance.

function 1:

```
def read_key
    puts "read pemkey: \"#{@pkey}\"" if @verbose
    File.open(@pkey, 'rb') do |io|
      @key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(io)
    end
  end
```

function 2:

```
def generate_key
    puts "generate pemkey to \"#{@pkey_o}\"" if @verbose
    @key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(KEY_SIZE)
    # save key
    File.open(@pkey_o, 'wb') do |file|
      file << @key.export()
    end
  end
```

function 3:

```
def sign_zip
    puts "sign zip" if @verbose
    plain = nil
    File.open(@zip, 'rb') do |file|
      plain = file.read
    end
    @sig = @key.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, plain)
  end
```

Comment: well, 1st function: \"#{@pkey_o}\ what is this? and then what @verbose means, is it read it from command line? then whats is the rb switch?(read in binary?) then do |IO|, whats that? also even if we use pkey without @ sign, this will work fine right? Then atlast OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(io) i didnt understand this line at all.
Now in the 2nd function: what does this do? "do |file|" is it a lop or something like that? then this file << @key.export() will write the contents of @key to that file i hope!
function 3: this sign() in key.sign() whats does it do? @zip is the path to zip
file i think.

Comment: https://github.com/Constellation/crxmake/blob/master/lib/crxmake.rb

Comment: I would highly recommend reading a book or tutorial on ruby before writing something in it. Most of what you are asking are around fundamental constructs in the language.

Comment: N00btip: It's called "Ruby", not "RUBY".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably two things about the above code that are confusing you, which if clarified, will help understand it.

First, @verbose and @key are instance variables, what a C++ programmer might call "member variables." The "if @verbose" following the puts statement literally means only do the puts if @verbose is true. @verbose never needs to be declared a bool--you just start using it. If it's never initialized, it's "nil" which evaluates to false.

Second, the do/end parts are code blocks. Many Ruby methods take a code block and execute it with a variable declared in those pipe characters. An example would be "array.each do |s| puts s; end" which might look like "for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) { s = array[i]; puts(s); }" in C++. For File.open, |io| is the file instance opened, and "read" is one of its methods.

Answer (score 1):

These are all methods. `#{@pkey_o}` is string interpolation, substituting in the contents of an instance variable (called `pkey_o`; Ruby instance variables begin with `@` and class variables – unused here – begin with `@@`).

```
File.open(@pkey, 'rb') do |io|
  @key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(io)
end
```

That opens the file whose name is stored in `@pkey`, stores the file handle in `io` (a block-local variable) and uses that with `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new`, whose result is stored in `@key`. Finally, it closes the file handle when the block is finished (at the `end`) whether or not it is a successful exit or an error case (in which case an exception would be thrown, but it would still be thrown). When translating this to C++, use of the RAII pattern is *entirely* reasonable (if you were going to Java, I'd say to use `try`/`finally`).